# OpenGL + MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.AV1 - a freezing video (like very low fps)

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

Android [declares](https://developer.android.com/media/platform/supported-formats#video-formats) that `AV1` video encoder is supported for Android 14+

Before I pass frames to `MediaRecorder` I process them with `OpenGL`:

```
recorderWindowSurface = WindowSurface(eglCore, recorderSurface, true)
recorderWindowSurface.makeCurrent()
```

I tried AV1 codec on Samsung S22 Ultra Android 14 and Android MediaRecorder:

```
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.AV1)                
recorderSurface = MediaCodec.createPersistentInputSurface()
mediaRecorder.setInputSurface(recorderSurface)
```

I tried to play a recording video but it plays very freezing / lagging.

I noticed that `EglSurfaceBase.swapBuffers()` ([source](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/gles/EglSurfaceBase.java#L135)) takes a lot of CPU time right now

```
164 ms
151 ms
153 ms
163 ms
150 ms
160 ms
158 ms
145 ms
158 ms
173 ms
191 ms
```

Did someone tried it on their devices, does it work well or similar results?

`MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264, MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.HEVC` - works without issues, same parameters (bitrate, full hd resolution, fps 20..30, nothing special).

`EglSurfaceBase.swapBuffers()` in this case takes:

```
8 ms 
10 ms
6 ms 
6 ms 
4 ms 
4 ms 
3 ms 
2 ms 
4 ms 
12 ms
```

MediaInfo:

```
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AV1
Format/Info                              : AOMedia Video 1
Format profile                           : Main@L4.0
Codec ID                                 : av01
Duration                                 : 4 s 55 ms
Source duration                          : 4 s 51 ms
Bit rate                                 : 6 210 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Rotation                                 : 90°
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 9.134 FPS
Minimum frame rate                       : 5.102 FPS
Maximum frame rate                       : 37.037 FPS
```